# Query Return Collection From MongoDb Mongoose in Node

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Is it possible to query a returned collection in mongoose for mongodb.  So in the example below I wish to return to the page the full list of steps, as well as the currentStep.  The line I am unsure about is currentStep: steps.?????(page).

Thanks

```
var page = (req.params.page == undefined?1:req.params.page)
db.stepModel.find().sort({number:1}).exec(function(err, steps) {
 if (err) { return next(err); }
 res.render('scheme', { 
   title: 'Fnol',
   user: req.user, 
   steps:steps,
   currentStep: steps.?????(page), 
   page:page
 });
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `steps` as an array:

```
currentStep : steps[page - 1].toObject()
```

The `- 1` is because it seems that you use 1-based indexing for the page, whereas arrays are 0-based.

The [`toObject()`](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#document_Document-toObject) converts the Mongoose result into a proper JS object, so you can access properties like `_id` from within your template.